# Fully-Importing MySQL database to Solr 4 gives 404 error

Tags: php, mysql, jdbc, solr

Yet another Solr 4 new user. I admired what is Solr able to do in full text searching, but the on-line documentation is a little bit frustrating. Anyway, I'm working on importing my MySQL database (having few millions of records) to Solr.

- I downloaded the Java connector and save it in the `example/lib` directory.
- I created `data-config.xml` and put within it:

  ```
  <document name="doc">
      <entity name="pagey" query="SELECT * FROM page">

          <field column="id" name="pid" />
          <field column="Content" name="pcontent" />
          <field column="bid" name="bid" />
          <field column="Num" name="num" />
      </entity>
  </document>
  ```

  and saved it in: `/example/solr/collection1/conf`.
- Linked that file to `solrconfig.xml` by adding:

  `<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
      <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
      </lst>
  </requestHandler>`
- Modified schema.xml to add my new fields.

But when I arrived to perform full importing by interring: `http://[localhost]:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import` I got this  error: `HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing /solr/dataimport. Reason: Not Found`. I think this is no more valid in the last version 4. So I    tried: `http://[localhost]:8983/solr/#/collection1/dataimport?command=full-import` but nothing happens.

My fields have been successfully added, I can see them on the admin panel in the schema browser section in collection1.

From the admin -> collection1 -> Dataimport, it show: `sorry, no dataimport-handler defined!`.
Running the `start.jar` doesn't show errors.

**What am I missing right here?**

**EDIT:** After solving it, remember that "XML is case-sensitive".

Comment: in your solrconfig.xml you show data-config.xml while you say your import settings are in data-import.xml... is that a typo or you really did so? and another issue with solr4.0 is that there are some weird changes for dataimport stuff, i had a similar issue with data importing at the begining too but after digging the mailing list i was able to run it... after you make the typo thing clear, i can put my config and other settings here if it still keeps failing
and it would be nice to see the part of your logs when you try to run dataimport

Comment: Thanks stephanruhl. Absolutely it's a typo, its name is `data-config.xml`. Thanks for pointing it out. I'd like to see what you did to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You data-config needs to look more like this.  You are not specifying a mysql host, user, or password.

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
   driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:8889/yourdatabase"
   user="mysql_user"
   password="mysql_password"/>

<document name="doc">
    <entity name="pagey" query="SELECT * FROM page">

        <field column="id" name="pid" />
        <field column="Content" name="pcontent" />
        <field column="bid" name="bid" />
        <field column="Num" name="num" />
    </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

You need to include this in your solrconfig.xml file.

```
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
```

and

```
  <requestHandler name="/dataimport"
     class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

In solr.xml you need to make sure you have the following

```
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="../lib">
```

Comment: The guy [here](http://blog.braslavsky.org/2010/12/installing-and-configure-apache-solr.html) deceived me; I just was reading the [official instructions](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart) when I noticed that "H" in `<requestHandler />` was in capital letter. I checked your reply to confirm so it was as so. "XML is case-sensitive" I was pretty sure it's not in my steps, I followed yours one by one and either the official quick start. Any way it's solved now. I thank you bikedorkseattle very much for your help.
Lesson: "Don't take any online tutorial as granted, people make mistakes".

Answer (score 1):

```
If you are using latest Solr then use 

<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />


instead of

<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
```